# How to reference classes in .net assembly in C++/CLI project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, c++-cli

I used to have a native C++ project that used a TLB to reference some class definitions, like shown below:

```
#import "Data.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids
```

And this native c++ had functions that used items from this TLB. So example:

```
MyClass::TransferData(_Scalars myScalars)
{
    // do transfer 
}
```

As seen above, `_Scalars` is an interface inside the TLB. This function's purpose was to transfer some data from MyClass (native C++) to GUI (VB6)

There's been a project change where the GUI has been converted to VB.NET, so I've changed the native c++ project to a managed/unmanaged C++/CLI project. So now, `Data.tlb` (which was generated from a VB6 project) - is now a VB.NET project, which can be added as a reference to my C++/CLI project!

So now that I have this reference, how can I actually use the classes in it? Obviously the function parameter _Scalars gives an error now, since I'm not using the TLB anymore.

Comment: Hi Hans, ultimately I guess my question is...I did "Add Reference" in my C++/CLI project to add a .NET Assembly. Now I want to use it in code. What's the syntax for this, I've searched all over the place!

Answer (score 0):

I would structure your project so that your GUI .NET project is not dependent on your core business logic projects. Additionally, I would still maintain a native C++ project, and create a new C++/CLI project purely for the purposes of interop. The C++/CLI project will be responsible for wrapping native classes with C++/CLI ref classes which can marshal any native objects into .NET objects or act as a proxy object. If your C++/CLI project has dependencies on other .NET classes, separate those classes into their own project e.g. Project.Models and add that project as a reference to your C++/CLI project.

So to answer your question further (if I understand your correctly) you can reference a .NET object in a native C++ class if you have /clr turned on however keep that layer to a minimum. An example, can be found here.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42319/Using-NET-Classes-Modules-from-Native-C. I.e. keep your above mentioned class out of the C++/CLI project.

Comment: Thanks. Just a question: lets say that the C++/CLI project has a dependency on a .NET class, so I add that as a reference to the C++/CLI project. Is it possible to expose the referenced assembly to the native code as well? (like through an interface?) Before, the definitions were coming from a TLB, so I'm just trying to figure out how the native code will know about the new .NET classes

Comment: Just to provide more info, my native C++ functions use IDispatch pointers, and these functions were originally called through COM. Going forward, how to change these functions to support .NET is the million dollar question. Ultimately, the workflow I think makes sense is: in GUI (.NET) load C++/CLI assembly (managed wrapper) -> wrapper creates a new native C++ object pointer -> call managed function from .NET -> pass (i guess marshal) .NET objects to native function.